# Order rows alphabetically after insert (not order by)

Tags: triggers, insert, alphabetical

I need some advise for making a trigger that orders alphabetically after every insert.

```
Example:
Table COUNTRIES
ID 1, name 'Germany'
ID 2, name 'Bahamas'
ID 3, name 'Algeria'

Afterwards:
ID 1, name 'Algeria'
ID 2, name 'Bahamas'
ID 3, name 'Germany'
```

Any thoughts on how achieve this? Thank you.

PD: `ORDER BY` used on a `SELECT` statement will only order the rows for "aesthetical" purposes, the real rows would have no order whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found an answer for this issue at http://sqlteam.com.

Maybe it will help some other users.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ORDER_COUNTRIES
AFTER INSERT
ON COUNTRIES
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE COUNTRIES
    SET name = Table3.name
    FROM Prueba Table1
    JOIN (SELECT ID, seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) FROM COUNTRIES) Table2
    ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
    JOIN (SELECT name, seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) FROM COUNTRIES) Table3
    ON Table2.seq = Table3.seq
END

Result:                                                                                                                            

ID 1, name 'Algeria'
ID 2, name 'Bahamas'
ID 3, name 'Germany'
```

Now the table gets properly ordered after every insert. So, if you `SELECT` either by using `ORDER BY` or not, your table will always be alphabetically ordered.

Answer found at http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=160974 from the user
"nigelrivett". All credit goes to him.